# std::bind in constructor to callback method in class

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I have a class `Foo` which is instanciated in class `Bar`.

I need to assign the `callback` of `m_foo` to the method of `Bar` called `xpto()`.
I should be able to use the `std::bind` here, correct? What is wrong with my code?

The class Foo:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(std::function<void()> cb);
}
```

The class Bar:

```
class Bar
{
public:
   Bar(std::function<void()> cb);

   void xpto();
private:
   Foo m_foo;
}

Bar::Bar(std::function<void()> cb)
: m_foo(std::bind(&xpto)) // ERROR!!!?
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a little off in your use of `bind()`:

```
class Bar
{
public:
   Bar(std::function<void()> cb);

   void xpto();
private:
   Foo m_foo;
}

Bar::Bar(std::function<void()> cb)
: m_foo(std::bind(&Bar::xpto, this)
{}
```

That should work. I'm not sure why you have the `cb` argument to the constructor of `Bar` though.

Comment: yes!! thanks! sorry, that argument is for something else (not related to this question. I forgot to remove it)